# Time complexity of this recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have this recursive function. I want to know the time complexity of this algorithm. The idea is given a number, we have to find all the subsets that sum to the give number

```
public void getSequences(int n, ArrayList<Integer> buffer, int sum) {
  if(sum == n) {
     for(int j=0; j<buffer.size(); j++) {
         System.out.print(buffer.get(j) + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");
  }

  for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
     sum += i;
     if(sum > n) {
       break;
     }
     buffer.add(i);
     getSequences(n, buffer, sum);
     sum -= i;
     buffer.remove(i);
  }
}

ArrayList<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
getSequences(3, buffer, 0);

// Output
// 1 1 1
// 1 2 
// 2 1
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: complexity is O(k), where k - amount of such subsets

Comment: `buffer.remove(i);` is incorrect and causes a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm sure you meant `buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);` but the edit I tried to make was rejected for not "maintaining the poster's original intent."

Answer (score 0):

Since the code generates every possible sequence that sums to n, and because order matters. It's asymptotic complexity is bound by the size of sequences.

Another way to count all of the sequences is to think as follows.

1. Start with `n` 1's.

   Example: 1 1 1 1 1
2. For some bitset of length `n-1`, reduce neighboring sequences if the bit is on for that index.

   Example: BitSet(0,1,0,0) yields sequence: 1 (1+1) 1 1 => 1 2 1 1

   Example: BitSet(1,1,0,1) yields sequence: (1+1+1) (1+1) => 3 2

Since a specific bitset of size `n-1` yields a unique sequence, then this algorithm is clearly O(2^n).